# Delta time in pandasql is rounded to days (not showing H, M, S)

Tags: mysql, pandas, timedelta, pandasql

I am trying to calculate the time delta between two timestamps and getting only time delta rounded to days. The difference in hours, minutes, or seconds is gone (this is not a case of multiplying by 24 or 60, etc. because I will be multiplying o). Tried many solutions, but nothing works. Any idea is welcomed. Thanks!

```
query = '''
WITH lagging_column as 
(SELECT 
ACCOUNT,
FULL_TABLE_NAME,
UPDATE_TIME as first_time, 
LAG(UPDATE_TIME) OVER(PARTITION BY ACCOUNT, FULL_TABLE_NAME ORDER BY UPDATE_TIME) as previous_time
FROM mont_df
ORDER BY ACCOUNT, FULL_TABLE_NAME, first_time)
Select
ACCOUNT,
FULL_TABLE_NAME,
first_time,
previous_time,
cast (first_time as timestamp)  - cast(previous_time as timestamp) as update_diff
from lagging_column 
where first_time != previous_time  
'''

mysql(query)
```

Comment: `cast (first_time as timestamp)  - cast(previous_time as timestamp)` - this is incorrect. Substraction (numeric context) converts TIMESTAMPs to BIGINT. Study https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-literals.html. Use TIMESTAMPDIFF then SEC_TO_TIME. PS. What is `UPDATE_TIME` column datatype in source table?

Comment: Hi Akina, Thanks for the tips. I'm trying them out. The original datatype is an object in python... Thanks